# Variables not resolving to members in interface method

Tags: typescript

I have an array of `IDoctor` and I get error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firstName'

...when I execute `console.log(testUser[0].getFullName())`.

I want to print `firstName` and `lastName` from the object.

```ts
export interface IPerson {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  getFullName: () => string;
  gender: Gender;
}

export interface IDoctor extends IPerson {
  doctorNo: number;
}

const testUser: IDoctor[] = [
    {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "a",
    lastName: "aa",
    getFullName: () =>  `Doctor First & Last Name: ${firstName} ${lastName}`,
    gender: Gender.Male,
    doctorNo: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: "b",
    lastName: "bb",
    getFullName: () => `Doctor First & Last Name: ${firstName} ${lastName}`,
    gender: Gender.Female,
    doctorNo: 2
  }
];  

console.log("First Doctor",testUser[0].getFullName());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied by MatthieuRiegler's answer, you have to tell where `firstName` and `lastName` come from, otherwise the TS/JS engine will look for these variables in scope (and find out that they do not exist in any parent scope, hence the error message).

With `this` keyword, we now specify that they come from the calling context. If using a `class` (as suggested by MatthieuRiegler's answer), that context is the class instance.

But it is very possible to achieve this without using classes yet. But we have to use normal [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#defining_methods) (functions), instead of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which do not have their own context:

> Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to `this` [...], and should not be used as methods.

(hence the new error message when trying to use arrow functions with `this` as methods: instead of referring to the object, it refers to the outer `class`, your `EmployeeComponent`)

Such methods can very well [use `this` to refer to the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#using_this_for_object_references) (which will be the calling context), without resorting to classes:

```
const testUser: IDoctor[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: "a",
        lastName: "aa",
        // Use a normal function as method; `this` refers to the calling context
        getFullName() {
            return `Doctor First & Last Name: ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
        },
        gender: Gender.Male,
        doctorNo: 1
    }
];

console.log(
    "First Doctor",
    // The calling context is what comes before the dot (.)
    // so `testUser[0]` here
    testUser[0].getFullName()
);
// [LOG]: "First Doctor",  "Doctor First & Last Name: a aa"
```

---

Since the `getFullName` method will be used in every `IDoctor`, and provided that the body is the same for all of them, it is possible to factorize it:

```
function getFullName(this: IPerson) {
    return `Doctor First & Last Name: ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
}
```

In that case, we have to tell explicitly to TypeScript what `this` will represent: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

Then we can use it in every object:

```
const testUser: IDoctor[] = [
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: "b",
        lastName: "bb",
        getFullName, // Use the factorized function
        gender: Gender.Female,
        doctorNo: 2
    }
];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA4qAmwBOUDeAoKWoFkCGANsADSbYBiwEhw6AvuugJYgAuyAZngMbBQCSABWQBnAPYg0ZLE3gAuKOAgAjZAG5pUDkyQjWAOTwRgCvUhYBzDdigE8ew8dOtzIK5ovBW5MAQKOTKAAKAEooAF4APigzS2tsTxBEJAU4JPV6RhZ2JC5eAQARMW5WMRRgAA92JJEBYV0JKRt4YtKkfTEFJVUkDQZ0bgk9KHY9AFURZAV+IpKygG0AXQioec0MGxtZBQBGUk3sbV0DI0CAIjwz-YPbexOnKAvL64OAeleoCb48RTLqAi0YBAJSYjXsUGMrAAFmJ4GooAADaFMEQIqBIYAcUQjMQjKF8biEAiWKCDNiVViaGyeby+fynUJNG42DGsMBISQI2ZtKDkHTDABkUAAMncoAEFAASVDIkQAOiODlOdCg0tlcrsSuMdAR8QOdBem0SyVSCGQcvwRENzVaZQ6u00BvWVOw2ygACZrYd+fdzsori6sJrfQozsp-V6sDSfH4AsQoO9PpM8Xw8m0mAAvYDwQHA1igkCBqDGqawM1IOWUf4kIstObtToex3oRYaAZDMREDViCxBTRnPnHKDcsoBmyJgAq+NJRJJZPYVSgKKgAHcoXhWKSxMZaqoOGU+NC+C1N0E5SFNInxIjRqwvkh5gAGRZo-EYzS3+9PxZy6N0gKhOgIRtomADqBJ4JIaZlJmh7ThwQIghIpBXiw+RMJuK5MH4UCqFAYCTDmLBQMAABuyAAJ6FLaSAoR8TAcCmuGwlRy5HjEpxyugYEQZI7A4ROADKq7rpuSJQiiaLLpUAAOxLcBhBAUdxHxQqwrAySIcjvCuulyqwFEycAIjcOYMmsHYbhymUFivHWIivOuSTKGIYgANavO6rwIXmBbympEAEAAxIg3B2K4FgALSypFLCRXgkU+UhhZJfmjR-rGDKytM9TiCAYQbNgrLspyI4oIOgoimKEqqjKEnyoqvoqmq9UancAQ6pkQA)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `firstName`/`lastName` like that, you're referencing variable that do not exist.

You might want to create a class `Person` & `Doctor` and then use `this`:

```
getFullName: () => `Doctor First & Last Name: ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`,
```

Comment: I tried getFullName: () => `Doctor First & Last Name: ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}` as well, it doesn't work. I get TS2339: Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'EmployeesComponent'.